# Sequelize Many-to-many querying model

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Have some troubles with querying data.
Have 2 models with many to many relationships.
1st - S3FileData, 2nd - Playlists, they are connected through PlaylistContent table.
Also S3FileData is connected with User with User has-many playlists.

I need to query S3Files which belongs to user, but are not presented in user playlist.

I have playlist Id,userId.

Also I need offset and limit methods, so I tried to query this using findAndCountAll

But got no luck with it.
Would be very appreciate for any help :)

Comment: Could you post what you tried? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require include(joins in SQL) that will connect all these tables.
Something like this but first you will need to intertwine your models(db tables) which will look something like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: Grant });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: Grant });
User.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(User);
Profile.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(Profile);
```

> Reference:
> https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html

Now, Once you are through the joins you'll require to use those joins using include keyword in your `findAll` (or `findAllAndCount` as per the requirement):

Some basic code (You will need to try and tweak accordingly, this is rough code):

```
  S3Files.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: user,
      attributes: ['some columns']
      include: {
        model: userPlaylist,          
        attributes: ['some columns'],
        required: false 
    },
    where: {[Op.and]: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('userPlaylist.userId'), 'is not' null)},
    attributes: ['some columns']
  ]
});
```

lastly for offset and limit you'll require basic SQL logic of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

sample snippet from official docs for offset and limit:

```
Project
  .findAndCountAll({
     where: {
        title: {
          [Op.like]: 'foo%'
        }
     },
     offset: 10,
     limit: 2
  })
```

> Reference for the same:
> https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html

Comment: Thanks!
But the problem is to get the data that is not present in intermediate table..:)

Comment: Actually that is exactly that the code I gave up is intended to do. You can tweak the code put findAll on the intermediate table and then left join the primary table you want to filter with having clause? All those work the same main point is to find the exact raw query you are expecting to fire and then find sequlize conversion of it.

Comment: Also try to show some attempts you did so correction could be done, blankly no one can help.